# What does A => A = a => a mean in scala

Tags: scala, syntax

I found following syntax in scala which i dont understand

```
object Category {
    def id[A]: A => A = a => a
}
```

Especially this part **A = a => a**

Who can it be translated in a more readable syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a method that returns a function which takes an `A` and returns another `A` and the function it is returning is an `identity` (you get a variable `a` of type `A` and just return it):

```
scala> object Category {
 |     def id[A]: A => A = a => a
 | }
defined module Category

scala> Category.id[Int]
res0: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> res0(0)
res2: Int = 0
```

Not sure what are you trying to achieve here to be honest.

Comment: I am learning about category theorie and found this code example and i just wanted to understand this syntax.

Answer (score 9):

This line:

```
def id[A]: A => A = a => a
```

defines a method named `id` which has a type argument `A`.

The return type of the method is `A => A`, which is: a function that takes an `A` and returns an `A`.

The part after the `=`: `a => a` is the body of the `id` method. It's a function literal for a function that takes a value `a` and returns the same thing `a`.

The part that you are specifically asking about: `A = a => a` is not a part by itself. The `A => A` is the return type of the method `id`, and the `a => a` is the body of the method. Just like with any other method, the `=` between these two parts separates the method declaration from the method body.

You could write the same thing like this:

```
def id[A]: Function1[A, A] = a => a
```

Comment: Where is `a` declared ? Lambda expression ?

Comment: @elm, yes, it's a lambda expression, the `a` is the argument to the lambda expression.

Comment: Also nice explanation